# How to find magnetic permeability of a mixed core?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, inductance

Inserting a ferromagnetic rod into the core of an inductor increases its inductance. If the change in inductance is known, the following equation can be used (or so I assume) to find the relative magnetic permeability of the core material:

$$
L=\frac{\mu_0\mu_rN^2A}{l}
$$

Where L is inductance, $μ_0$ is magnetic permeability of free space, $\mu_r$ is relative permeability of the core material, $N$ is no. of coils in the inductor, $A$ is cross-sectional area of the inductor and $l$ is the length of the inductor wire.

My question is, once the magnetic permeability of the core has been obtained, how does one find the magnetic permeability of the rod? Since the core of the inductor consists of both air, and the ferromagnetic rod, the air would act as an insulator, and the μ value for the core would not be the same as the $\mu$ of the rod. I have assumed that the following formula would be accurate:

$$
\mbox{permeability calculated}\times\mbox{total volume}=\\=\mbox{permeability of rod}+\mbox{permeability of air}\times\mbox{volume of air}
$$

But I'm not sure if there are more factors, e.g. shape of the rod, position of the rod within the inductor core that have to be taken into account.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE. Please use LaTeX to write your equations

Comment: Pretty sure the shape of the rod would have to be taken into account. In general you would need to solve the underlying Ampere's Law equation with all the geometry taken into account. Are you looking to get into that, or are you looking for references to literature where this equation has been solved, and maybe a lookup table of some sort is given?

Comment: e.g. something like [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor#Inductance_formulas), formulas with no explanation, but for not just air core

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking more for references to literature where the equation had been solved.